# Is there any good ASP.Net MVC project with TDD & MOQ Source code available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, open-source, tdd, moq

i'm starting to learn TDD, Unit-testing on asp.net mvc and i'm trying to pickup all these mocking via MOQ.

so i'm looking for any good asp.net mvc projects which source codes are made available to mere mortals like me :)

i've found some good asp.net mvc source codes but not those that uses MOQ specifically.

- [the asp.net mvc source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=aspnet&changeSetId=23011#)
- [code camp server](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/)
- [suteki shop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/)

So does anybody know any good open source asp.net mvc project which have good test/tdd examples using MOQ?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a sample/tutorial application rather than an open source project, but I think it meets your criteria:

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: nice, i didn't realize that they've change the mock framework too. the older nerddinner uses rhinomocks. but it uses vs2010, so i guess i have to use the newer version.

Comment: @Melaos - I think it uses MOQ, not 100% sure, but from memory it does.

Comment: the new one does, i saw the moq.dll inside, i'll be installing vs2010 express to test it out :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the [Kigg](http://kigg.codeplex.com/) project is an excellent example of applying TDD (and other best pracices such as DI, appropriate use of mocks/stubs) principles in an MVC project.  As a bonus, the project uses Moq extensively.